# Serving static files using mod_wsgi-express with ProxyPass in Apache is not working

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I found out [mod_wsgi-express](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/introducing-modwsgi-express.html) today and I think it is really cool project.
I can't believe this single command is all needed to deploy Python/Django web applications.

```
mod_wsgi-express start-server project/wsgi.py
```

However, documentation seems to be still missing (or I didn't find?). As far as I see, it is not mentioned in official docs [here](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/index.html).

I am hosting couple of small sites on same machine, thus using VirtualHost. So I need to proxy it to another port like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName example.com
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8000"
</VirtualHost>
```

So far so good. I am running mod_wsgi-express as follows:

```
mod_wsgi-express start-server --url-alias /static /path/to/static project/wsgi.py
```

You see, I am trying to set static files config in mod_wsgi-express itself. However, static files are not served and gives 502 Proxy Error.

So proxying dynamic requests is working, but not static files. Site is also working file when accessed directly at port 8000. What am I missing here?

Off course I could add config in VirtualHost itself to serve these static files, but if it works with mod_wsgi-express, it would make configuration a lot simpler and easier to deploy.

Comment: For setting up Apache as proxy in front of mod_wsgi-express you may want to read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/06/proxying-to-python-web-application.html and http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/07/redirection-problems-when-proxying-to.html Ignore the fact that it had mod_wsgi-express running in Docker. Same concepts apply.

Comment: Thank you very much @GrahamDumpleton

Second post is indeed very detailed about above issue. I was easily able to fix the issue following your post. Kudos :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Graham Dumpleton for comment above. Even though it is not there in official documentation, he has written detailed blog post about this issue: [Redirection problems when proxying to Apache running in Docker..](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/07/redirection-problems-when-proxying-to.html)

While I am not using Docker, this solution is generic when proxying requests to different port than 80 or 443 from Apache VirtualHost.

In my case above, I was missing two headers in VirtualHost configuration. So this is new VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 80
</VirtualHost>
```

That's all that is needed. Graham provides lots of detail in his blog post, so worth reading if you face similar issues.